# Headless Chrome screenshot with file permission

Tags: google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am using headless chromium-browser to take screenshots. But the problem I am facing is that the file has only read-write permission to the user itself. No other user/group has read permission. I want to provide read permission to any other user. But still couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: You will  need to provide a lot more detail. Why can't the program that is ordering Chrome around set the permissions?

Comment: I did searched for something like this. Precisely, when running headless chrome command to take screenshot passing the permissions with some flag. But couldn't find any flag that fits my use-case

Comment: Why do you need a flag? WHy not change the access after you grab the screenshot? Also, Chromium is open source, you could always add your own. Finally, umask?

Comment: I solved it using that..Took the screenshot and then used chmod to changed the permissions for the file.